# MAXIMO 7.6 - how to display a dialog (Report Downtime in WOTRACK for example) using automation script

Tags: maximo

Doing this from java bean is easy - RequestHandler.showDialog(this.sessionContext, "repdown");

But how to do the same from the automation script?

Please note, I'm asking how to show a dialog, not a message box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that Automation Scripts still run in the businessobjects space, like Mbo customizations, and not in the maximouiweb space, like Bean customizations, what you want to do cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Preacher.